# How to take just one phase from 3p4w System?

Tags: circuit-design, ac

I am looking for a circuit solution to take just one phase from three phases that not all must be active. The idea is to feed an AC 220V load  from any active phase.

If some phase is down the load must be fed.

[image]

Any simple Idea?

The best way should be using discrete components, such as transistors,triacs..

is that possible with TRIACs? :

[image]

Comment: can be done with some relays. Sit down with a pencil and paper to resolve the logic. then implement.

Comment: What is your criteria of "phase down" ?

Comment: Transistors and triacs are not passive components. Resistors, capacitors and inductors are passive. Do you mean "discrete" components? Your question still has no details about the load type, current requirements and power factor.

Comment: sorry, discrete components not mechanical

Comment: phase down, is when some of the three phases are open circuit

Comment: That makes life easier : if "phase down" meant slightly low on voltage, it would be more difficult. Relays are discrete components, just bigger ones. (Consider SSRs, Solid State Relays, if you object to mechanical ones. But keep it simple as per the answer; so forget transistors.)

Comment: You are going through a lot of hoops for a microcontroller.  Odds are that if one-phase is out, all three are out (ganged circuit breakers) from a power companies perspective.

Comment: Relays can provide a robust solution. | TRIACS and some other discrete components can work but isolation is an issue and noise is more likely to cause magic smoke. Some simple logic (digital discrete or microcontroller, or analog plus relays or TRIACS is entirely doable. | Explaining the what and the why of the requirement would help.

Comment: This question has effectively been superseded by [a newer version](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/588718/how-to-keep-a-220v-bulb-on-using-3-phases-simultaneously) from the same OP. Community response was against updating this one. Therefore to avoid readers spending time answering this question, which has become obsolete (and was changed to add a constraint of wanting a sold-state solution after an answer using relays had been provided), this question has been closed as a duplicate of that later one, where the constraints and requirements are better explained.

Answer (score 4):

Note: This answer was written before the question was changed to require a solution using TRIACs.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdaQ2l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Magic relay priority circuit. (Don't omit the fuses.)*

- If L1 and L2 are on power is provided by L1.
- If L1 is off and L2 is on then power is provided by L2.
- If L1 and L2 are off then power is provided by L3.

Contacts need to be rated for full switching power. Note that some loads - particularly motors - will draw high current when the voltage phase changes by 120°.

The relays should probably be AC contactors.

---

Since you seem to require this for a small SMPS DC power supply some small ice-cube relays would be an excellent choice.

[image]

*Figure 2. A selection of ice-cube relays.*

These will take up less space than an electronic solution unless you spend a lot of effort on design and PCB build. They will also be safe and reliable.

Comment: pretty good idea if we use transistors instead of relays :) the question is how to move the transistor gates with AC

Comment: Are you asking if you can use transistors instead of relays? This was not a requirement in your question and there isn't enough information about the load to answer that question.

Comment: sorry, I have been already updated my question

Comment: Transistors are generally not suitable for switching AC loads - particularly at mains voltages and currents. Mechanical relays are simple and reliable. A semiconductor solution will be far more complex, less reliable and difficult to build and maintain. You still haven't supplied the details requested on load current and power factor.

Comment: you want simple, but suggest the 'best' way is to use semiconductors. You had two people suggest relays, so your definition of 'best' obviously isnt 'best' for us. Why do you want to use semiconductors? Any use of a semiconductor would require extra protection circuitry and be more difficult to design. Remember, this is not a design service.

Comment: Maybe relays are a good but they take a lot of physical space in a circuit also the prices are much higher than a couple of triacs or so.. I am now finding out to solve it with with triacs but the logic is a little complex at least for me. By the way the load is max ~400mA

Comment: What IS the load? More importantly, does the load require AC?

Comment: The load must be because there will be an AC-DC transformer to power a tiny microcontroller. The idea is to get the MCU powered at any time also if any phase is not working.

Comment: All that information is missing from your question.

Comment: What about using three transformers and joining their DC output with Schottky diodes, or just paralleling them *if they are designed to handle that*? In that case, you are not only prepared for phase outage, but also for supply failure.

Comment: As the transistor say, you should add key information to your question.

Comment: My question is a general purpose question, all this content can be used later for another people. Of course the question is spreading out when you place a particular situation. Transformers + diodes are a good idea but still they take too much space and they are not budget frendly. I am still thinking on how to control the gates of the TRIACs to get that logic working